# Ansible: How to use examples from the documentation?

Tags: module, ansible, yaml

I'm starting to learn Ansible and for this I copy and paste examples from the documentation. For example this one

```yaml
- name: Check that a page returns a status 200 and fail if the word AWESOME is not in the page contents
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: http://www.example.com
    return_content: yes
  register: this
  failed_when: "'AWESOME' not in this.content"
```

which I've found in [`uri`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html) module documentation.

Every single time I do this, whatever the module I get:

```
ERROR! 'ansible.builtin.uri' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to have been in '/home/alfrerra/test2.yml': line 1, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

- name: Check that a page returns a status 200 and fail if the word AWESOME is not in the page contents
  ^ here
```

I have only 2 playbooks that only ping successfully:

```yaml
-
  name: ping localhost
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: ping test
      ping
```

and

```yaml
---
  - name: ping localhost
    hosts: localhost
    tasks:
      - name: ping test
        ping
```

So I adapted the example to match these 2 examples, but to no avail so far.

I'm sure it's nothing much but it's driving me crazy.

Comment: Most of what you will find in the documentation of modules are tasks. So you should use them as you are using the ping module, with a play structure, as prompted by the error. So, your uri task should be in a list under a `tasks` option.

Comment: You have to read (at least) [intro to playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_intro.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned within the comments, the documentation are to show how to use certain parameter of certain modules within a single task. They are not mentioned to work in a copy and paste manner by itself or only.

You may have a look into the following [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Check that a page returns a status 200 and fail if the word 'iana.org' is not in the page contents
    uri:
      url: http://www.example.com
      return_content: yes
    environment:
      http_proxy: "localhost:3128"
      https_proxy: "localhost:3128"
    register: this
    failed_when: "'iana.org' not in this.content"

  - name: Show content
    debug:
      msg: "{{ this.content }}"
```

resulting into the output of the page content.

Please take note that the web page of the example domain is connected and delivers a valid result, but it does not contain the word AWESOME. To address this the string to lookup was changed to the page owner `iana.org` and to not let the task fail. Furthermore and since working behind a proxy it was necessary to address the proxy configuration and which you probably need to remove again.

Your first example is a single task and failing therefore with `ERROR! ... not a valid attribute for a Play`. Your second and
third examples are playbooks with a single task and therefore executing.

**Documentation**

- [Module format and documentation - EXAMPLES block](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_documenting.html#examples-block)

  > *... show users how your module works with real-world examples in multi-line plain-text YAML format. The best examples are ready for the user to **copy and paste into a playbook**.*
- [Ansible playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_intro.html)

Answer (score -1):

`failed_when` must be a comparison or a boolean.

example  :

```yaml
- name: Check that a page returns AWESOME is not in the page contents 
  ansible.builtin.uri: 
    url: http://www.example.com 
    return_content: yes 
  register: this 
  failed_when: this.rc == 0;
```

It will execute the task only if the return value is equal to 0

Comment: The `failed_when:` expression in OP is returning a boolean => `"'AWESOME' not in this.content"` means when the list `this.content` does not contain an element being the string `'AWESOME`". So how can the above possibly answer the question? (which is not about a problem on a `failed_when` stanza anyway).