# How can I check an URL with uri module and loop?

Tags: loops, ansible, uri

I'm trying to check URL's with the `uri` module and a loop of course because I have more than one URL.

```yaml
---
- name: check URLs with a loop
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    url:
      - https://www.google.com
      - https://example.com
      - https://www.wikipedia.org

 tasks:
   - name: test url
     uri:
       url: "{{ item }}"
     loop:
      - "{{ url }}"
```

Comment: Since this seems to be description of what you are trying to do only, can you describe in more detail what is the question, or which problems or errors you are observing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a look into the following minimal example.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Check that a page returns a status 200
    uri:
      url: "{{ item }}"
      return_content: yes
    register: this
    loop:
      - http://www.example.com
      - http://www.example.org

  - name: Show content with loop
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.content }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item.url }}"
    loop: "{{ this.results }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Check that a page returns a status 200] *****
ok: [localhost] => (item=http://www.example.com)
ok: [localhost] => (item=http://www.example.org)

TASK [Show content with loop] *********************
ok: [localhost] => (item=http://www.example.com) =>
  msg: |-
    <!doctype html>
    ...
ok: [localhost] => (item=http://www.example.org) =>
  msg: |-
    <!doctype html>
    ...
```

As you see can from the [`debug`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html) task the data structure of the result set changed in compare to the [former given example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74610945/6771046). Therefore it is recommend to get familiar with it by using additional tasks like

```yaml
- name: Show var
    debug:
      var: this.results

  - name: Show content with filter
    debug:
      msg: "{{ this.results | map(attribute='content') }}"
```

**Further Documentation**

- [Registering variables with a loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop)
- [Limiting loop output with label](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#limiting-loop-output-with-label)
- [Using filters to manipulate data](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html)
- Jinja2 Template Designer Documentation - [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.map) filter